# Is this a plausible reaction mechanism? (H2SO4 cyclization after Friedel-Crafts)

Tags: organic-chemistry

in my undergraduate chemistry lab we synthesized the substituted benzene on the left in a Friedel-Crafts reaction. 
As a next step we're supposed to reflux for 1.5h at 90°C with concentrated sulfuric acid and obtain the product on the right. A bicyclical product.

We have to come up with a plausible mechanism for the ring closure reaction and I am unsure that what I came up with makes sense or not.

Thank you!

[image]

edit: this is the FC reaction we did in the first step:
[image]

The Steps for this reaction are as follows: 
To a Solution of AlCl3 in abs. DCM the following reagents were added: 
-3-chloropropionic chloride.
-p-xylene.
The reaction mixture was stirred at rt for 1h.
Then added to a mixture of 1:1 conc. HCl and ice water.
Then extracted with DCM in a separatory funnel.
Washed twice with a sat. NaCl solution. 
The organic phases were dried with MgSO4. 
The DCM was then removed in the rotary evaporator.
A yellow-orange Solution was left at the end. 
It was left to crystallize over night.

Now this is where the second part happens, the H2SO4-cyclisation reaction. 
.......
Some comments suggested that there might be a hydrolyzed intermediate with a displaced chloride. Here is my take on how that would look like:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you made the starting material shown by the F-C reaction? What went into it?

Comment: Yes, I'm reasonably sure that it's the product. We began with para-xylene, 3-Chloropropionyl chloride, AlCl3 as the catalyst. (DCM was the solvent)

Comment: OK, that looks to be the correct intermediate. It's just that the H2SO4 cyclisation conditions would be far more appropriate for cyclising a carboxylic acid. What solvent is the cyclisation done in?

Comment: H2SO4 has to be added to the starting material which is crystalline. After the reflux step, there's an aqueous workup and an extraction with ether.
Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: That simply does not make sense according to me. If anything, you'd add another aryl to carbonyl.

Comment: My thought on that is that the path I chose is the kinetically favored one. Or to put it differently, intramolecular reactions are favored above intermolecular reactions. But maybe the bicyclical product isn't the only one being formed, maybe it's just the preferred one.

Comment: And if the aryl were to add to the carbonyl, it would be the double bond of the enolate acting as the nucleophile, right? But isn't it too bulky then?

Comment: No, the protonated ketone (bottom left) is a substrate for electrophilic attack by the second aryl. How strong is the sulfuric acid used in the cyclisation step? 98% cH2SO4?

Comment: You should investigate the Nazarov reaction.

Comment: There's obviously some detail missing here. Is there a work up after the FC reaction or is sulfuric acid simply added in? I'd this isn't 98% then water is going in too which potentially backs up the thoughts around a hydrolysed intermediate being cyclised. Also, to hit 90 degrees, the DCM has to be removed for standard batch reaction.

Comment: @Beerhunter There's a work up with a 1:1 mixture of HCl and water.  The DCM is removed with a rotary evaporator. It's just  the conc H2SO4 in the flasc at the beginning of the cyclization. (I've edited my post and added the details of the initial steps).

Comment: @Waylander I haven't started the cyclization step yet, so I'm not entirely sure what exact concentration the conc. H2SO4 has. Bit I think it's 98%.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines as @Beerhunter that there could be displacement of the Cl with OH, to give a primary alcohol

Comment: I've edited the post with my 2 cents on how the mechanism would work if there were a hydrolyzed intermediate.

Comment: @Michael would have been interesting see if you ended up with oligomeric mess or product if you'd added more Lewis acid and a higher b.p. solvent instead of doing the work up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose the mechanism illustrated below, which would seem plausible in concentrated sulfuric acid:[image: Proposed electrophilic mechanism of ring closure]

Comment: I'm doubtful about the mechanism of your chloride elimination

Comment: your mechanism is in line with the Nazarov Cyclization, interesting!

Comment: I think an allyl chloride with an electron donating OH group conjugated in the 3 position could likely solvolyze in concentrated sulfuric acid. Then the electrophilic substitution is intramolecular, therefore favorable.

Comment: I had the reaction today and this was more or less the accepted mechanism. Thanks!